# Getting Data in JList via JDBC - The missing link

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, arraylist, jlist

I've been stuck at a seemingly simple problem for hours and I just can't find the solution. I'm trying to implement a very simple Forum in Java and I'm trying to load the entrys at the moment.

My forum is a JList that is filled with JPanels and that accepts entries via the JLists `DefaultListModel` and the `addMessage` method. So if I add an entry without the database it looks like this:

```
MessageList m = new MessageList(); 

m.addMessage("NAME AUTOR", "<html><body style='width: 675px;'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.", "22.01.13", "SOA");
```

The messageList class looks like this:

```
public class MessageList extends JList{

DefaultListModel messageModel = new DefaultListModel();

  MessageRenderer messageRenderer = new MessageRenderer();

     public MessageList( ){
        this.setCellRenderer(messageRenderer);
        this.setModel(messageModel);

     }

     public void addMessage(String author, String text, String date, String tag){
         messageModel.addElement(new Message(author, text, date, tag));
     }

}
```

I've also written the Code for getting an `ArrayList` (called `allBtr`) with the Message Objects (called `ConBeitrag`) from the database:

```
ArrayList<ConBeitrag> allBtr = new ArrayList<ConBeitrag>();

ConBeitrag conBtr = new ConBeitrag();

try {
    allBtr = conBtr.getAllBtr();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The message objects look like this:

```
public class ConBeitrag {

    private int beitragid;
    private int projektid;
    private int mitarbeiterid;
    private String beitragText;
    private String erstellt_am;
    private String geaendert_am;
    private String schlagwort1;
    private String schlagwort2;

    private  MdBeitrag mdBtr = new MdBeitrag();

    public ConBeitrag (){

    }

    public ConBeitrag(int beitragid, int projektid, int mitarbeiterid, String beitragText, String erstellt_am, String geaendert_am){

        this.beitragid = beitragid;
        this.projektid = projektid;
        this.mitarbeiterid = mitarbeiterid;
        this.erstellt_am = erstellt_am;
        this.geaendert_am = geaendert_am;
        this.beitragText = beitragText;
        this.schlagwort1 = schlagwort1;
        this.schlagwort2 = schlagwort2;
    }

    public ArrayList<ConBeitrag> getAllBtr() throws SQLException{

        MdBtrInterface modInt;
        modInt = new MdBeitrag();

        ArrayList<ConBeitrag> AlBtr = modInt.getAllBtr();

        for(ConBeitrag object: AlBtr){
              System.out.println(object.beitragText);
        }

        return AlBtr;

    }
}
```

Now what would be the smartest way to get the `ArrayList` into a form that I can pass into the `addMessage` method? I've kind of approached this from the GUI end, then from the database end, and now I'm stuck in the middle.

Overwritten toString() method:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
     return mitarbeiterid + beitragstext + erstellt_am + schlagwort1 + schlagwort2; 
}
```

Comment: Is `ConBeitrag` "Message" is some other language?

Comment: Yes some terms are German. "ConBeitrag" is more or less "ConMessage".

Comment: What happens when you try and `addMessage()`?

Comment: addMessage() as it is used in the first code snippet works fine. But I want to use the ConBeitrag objects that I store in the ArrayList to add Messages. My problem is I don't know how to pass the ArrayList to the addMessage() method. Or what steps I need to undertake to make that possible.

Comment: Are all the messages coming from a database? And What is `<html><body style='width: 675px;'>` supposed to do?

Comment: The html makes sure the text doesn't flow out of the JPanel. But that can be ignored for now.

Yes the messages are coming from the database and are added to the ArrayList as you can see in the 4th code snippet with the getAllBtr() method.

Comment: The messages are stored inside the ArrayList as Objects if that helps. So if I run "System.out.println(allBtr);" it gives me "[ConBeitrag@48f4104f, ConBeitrag@f5ad7f4, ConBeitrag@1517dc0c]".

Comment: Take a look at my answer, see if that helps. Let me know. If It doesn't, I'll offer another possible solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"The messages are stored inside the ArrayList as Objects if that helps. So if I run "System.out.println(allBtr);" it gives me "[ConBeitrag@48f4104f, ConBeitrag@f5ad7f4, ConBeitrag@1517dc0c]"*

You need to override the `toString` method in your `ConGeitrag` class. Something like this.

```
    public class ConBeitrag {      
         ...

         @Override
         public String toString(){
              return author + ", " + text + ", " + date + ", " + tag; 
         }
    }
```

You can make the `return` any format you want. Test this one out and make changes as desired to the format.

Try this out as a Helper method (after you've overridden the toString)

```
    public JList createJList(ResultSet rs){

        DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();

        while (rs.next()){
            String author = rs.getString("author");   // Just an example. You may
            String text = rs.getString("text");       // need to retrieve your
            String date = rs.getString("date");       // data differently
            String tag = rs.getString("tag");

            Message message = new Message(author, text, date, tag);
            model.addElement(message);
        }

        JList list = new JList(model);

        return list; 
    }
```

I don't really see a need for a Custom JList for this situation.

**Test run:**  output : `3testtestnullnull`. Besides the formatting, it works fine

```
public class ConBeitragTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConBeitrag con = new ConBeitrag(1, 2, 3, "test", "test", "test");
        System.out.println(con);
    }
}

class ConBeitrag {

    private int beitragid;
    private int projektid;
    private int mitarbeiterid;
    private String beitragText;
    private String erstellt_am;
    private String geaendert_am;
    private String schlagwort1;
    private String schlagwort2;

    public ConBeitrag() {

    }

    public ConBeitrag(int beitragid, int projektid, int mitarbeiterid, String beitragText, String erstellt_am, String geaendert_am) {

        this.beitragid = beitragid;
        this.projektid = projektid;
        this.mitarbeiterid = mitarbeiterid;
        this.erstellt_am = erstellt_am;
        this.geaendert_am = geaendert_am;
        this.beitragText = beitragText;
        this.schlagwort1 = schlagwort1;         // This is null
        this.schlagwort2 = schlagwort2;         // This is null
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return mitarbeiterid + beitragText + erstellt_am + schlagwort1 + schlagwort2;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hmm I think that should be it, but strangely it won't work. I implemented the method toString in ConBeitrag like you describe but if I call toString() on an ConBeitrag object it still prints ConBeitrag@f5ad7f4. Shouldn't it now print out something in the format we specified in the return statement? I run System.out.println(a.toString()); where a is a ConBeitrag object I specified with ConBeitrag a = allBtr.get(0);.

Comment: Updated it, the exact syntax of the return statement isn't implemented yet of course.

Comment: Hmm where are you using toString in your example? I see you implementing it, but not calling it? Or is it automatically called when you use println?

Comment: You don't need to call it. That's the magic of it. It automatically prints it in the toString format

Comment: That's really strange I create the object with: ConBeitrag a = new ConBeitrag(1, 2, 3, "test", "test", "test"); just like you do and then I run System.out.println(a); and it still gives me ConBeitrag@f5ad7f4. The toString method is implemented exactly like in your example.

Comment: Runs fine as expected. But in my case it still doesn't work. Errors like this drive me crazy...

Comment: Oh man you are absolutely right (again). I placed the method in the wrong version of the ConBeitrag class. Time to clean up my Eclipse workspace... Thank you so much for your help!